# In SAS, how to compare characters in one string separated by '/'

Tags: arrays, sas, string-comparison

I'm new to SAS. Here is my problem. Suppose I have the following dataset named **data**:

`id     string
 1      Comm Bank/Comm Bank
 2      Comm Bank/Cash Flow
 3      Financial Statement/Financial Statement/Financial Statement
 4      Comm Bank/Wealth Management/Real Estate
 5      Comm Bank/Cash Flow/Comm Bank`

And I wish to create a flag followed by the rules: 
If all characters separated by `/` are the same, then flag = 0 otherwise flag = 1.
For example, the obs 1 has characters `Comm Bank` and `Comm Bank` and they are the same, then `flag = 0`. But for the obs 5, since there is a different `Cash Flow`, so the `flag = 1`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should post what you've tried. Look into the SCAN function as well as COUNTC to control a loop structure.

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to compare the first word to each of the others. You can stop when you find that one does not match.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  flag=0
  word1 = scan(string,1,'/');
  do i=2 to countw(string,'/') while (flag=0);
    if word1 ne scan(string,i,'/') then flag=1;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Tom! But I guess it should be like: do i=2 to (countw(string,'\')+1) while (flag=0)? Thank you anyway, my problem has been solved!

Comment: The N + 1 word will be empty.  You don't want to include that in the loop.  Perhaps you are thinking about `COUNTC()` which count occurrences of a character instead of `COUNTW()` that counts the number of words?

Comment: You are right! I by accident put COUNTC instead of COUNTW in the program.